# How do I know how much was written to an SSD over its lifetime?

Tags: ssd, smart

To assess the remaining reliability of my SSD I would like to know how much was written to an SSD over its lifetime. How can I learn this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command `smartctl -data -A /dev/sda` (replace `sda` with whichever drive your SSD is.

Depending on which SSD you have, the amount of writes may show as one of the values along with wear indicator or life left information.

Comment: Thanks! [Here's what I get](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7705984/). AFAICT, the number I'm looking for is 'NAND_Writes_1GiB' which shows 6160; which is a bit over 6 TB. My drive is 120 GB Intel 520, which should mean it was written about 50 times on average; not too much. Now, the question is: does automatic wear leveling work? But that's [another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/488465/181242).

Comment: I tried `sudo smartctl -data -A /dev/nvme0` and get the error `Read Device Identity failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: For nvme SSD drives use `sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0`