# Can I count on SSD to distribute wear evenly?

Tags: ssd, partitioning

I [checked](https://askubuntu.com/q/488442/181242) my SSD to see how much I have written to it over its lifetime to estimate how much life might be left in it. Currently, it the wear
amounts to about 50 write cycles, which isn't much, [this particular one is rated at 5000](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5518/a-look-at-enterprise-performance-of-intel-ssds) and SSDs in general should last at least 1000.

Now, the question is:

1. Can I count on SSD to distribute its wear more or less equally
   across all of its cells or 50 cycles on average might as well mean
   that some cells have endured, say, 500 or more?
2. If I create partitions on the drive, does wear leveling work across
   partitions? E.g. if I created a 8 GB swap partition on a 120 GB
   drive, did I just subject 1/15 th of the drive to disproportionately
   higher wear? Maybe I would be better off if I allocated extra space
   to swap partition, then. I started thinking of this issue
   specifically because I wanted to enable hibernation on my computer,
   and I started wondering whether I should ensure there's space
   equaling RAM on swap partition (if wear leveling across partitions
   work) or several times that (if it doesn't; to prolong SSD's
   lifespan)

My SSD is currently Intel 520 120GB and I'm considering using Intel and Samsung SSDs in the future.

Comment: You are starting to ask detailed technical questions more about hardware then about Ubuntu , let along linux. See http://thessdguy.com/tag/bad-blocks/ or the technical specifications of your drive (from the manufacturer). The short answer is you drive has a long but finite life span. In my experience, as the number of bad sectors increase the drive becomes less reliable. At some point you will have complete failure, perhaps with little or no warning. If you have valuable data on the device, back it up to an external media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the disk is very likely to distribute wear evenly, as they are usually engineered to do so, but it is not an ubuntu issue, it is mainly about the hardware. Don't really worry about it, but don't blame ubuntu if it fails.